# Opening links within tabs

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, panel

At present I have some jQuery tabs and these tabs contain links. Unfortunately on following one of the links, the new page opens as if you were following any normal link i.e. not within the tab which is want I would want to happen.

Have tried following this section but to no avail: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="redmond/jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
     $("a", ui.panel).click(function() {
       $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
       return false;
     });
    }
  });
 });
 </script>

</head>
<body>



<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
 <a href="page.html">link</a>
  <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
 <a href="page.html">link</a>
  <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
  <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
  <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the events are being attached to the anchor tags? Insert an alert or something on the click to make sure the event is being attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this after your current `.tabs()` call:

```
$('.ui-tabs-panel a').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.ui-tabs-panel').load(this.href);
  return false;
});
```

The issue is that you're not initially loading the pages as ajax, the content is there with the page loads (meaning that `load` event isn't firing yet).  To fix this,  in addition to hooking up the click handler when new content loads, you need to rig it up on `document.ready` as well.

Alternatively, you could replace the both `load` event and the above code with a single [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $('.ui-tabs-panel a').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.ui-tabs-panel').load(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```